Magic Trick perfomed at a theater and people wake up at a different place
I cant seem to recall a movie where a magician tries to perform a trick where he ends putting people to sleep and then these people wake up at a different place. There is a scene where these people are shown being loaded into big vans and are carefully placed in order as they were sitting in the theater where the magician was performing his act.

Do you have any idea how old this movie is or where it was set? Give all the information you can to help identify a movie.

If my answer is right (which I think it is) please mark it as correct. Thanks.

Though your description could've used some more detail (possible year(s), genre, whether the whole movie was about magic or just that scene etc), I think I have a possible match. 
The Incredible Burt Wonderstone (2013)

summary of the scene matching your description:

At the show, Gray's performance involves him drilling into his brain,
  claiming it will not affect him. This however, backfires, leaving Gray
  with brain damage. Holloway then introduces Burt, Anton, and Jane's
  performance, the "Disappearing Audience". The group secretly sedates
  the audience with sleeping gas and then transports them to an outside
  location in the same seating locations. The audience awakes and
  responds with awe, and Doug awards the headlining act to Burt and
  Anton; they ask Jane to be their opening act. The trio then performs
  the Disappearing Audience trick again, returning everyone to the
  casino theater, as now mentally-impaired Gray watches on with the
  drill bit still in his skull.
As the film ends, the final scene shows how Burt, Anton, Holloway and
  others transported the audience to the open area, by unceremoniously
  dragging and transporting the unconscious audience members to the
  area, and hauling them back to the theater in a moving van.

